# Как посчитать сложность алгоритма?

Tags: java, алгоритм, сложность

Исходные данные: файл, с одной единственной колонкой, в которой находятся числа от 0 до Integer.MAX_INT.

Нужно написать алгоритм, который будет подсчитывать количество повторений цифр в этом файле.

---

Будем считать, что у нас бесконечное количество памяти. Напишем такой метод, а по завершению просто распечатаем entries у этой коллекции:

```
final Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
//----

public void add(Integer digit) {
    Integer quantity = map.get(digit);

    if (quantity == null) {
        map.put(digit, 1);
    } else {
        map.put(digit, ++quantity);
    }
}
```

**Вопрос №1:** Правильно ли я понимаю, что алгоритмическая сложность данного метода будет O(1)? Т.к. внутри используется HashMap со сложностью поиска и добавления O(1).

**Вопрос №2:** Общая сложность системы будет равна O(n) ?

---

А теперь заменим `HashMap` на `TreeMap`:

**Вопрос №3:** Сложность **метода** будет равна O(log(n)) ?

**Вопрос №4:** Сложность всей системы будет равен O(n) ? Т.к. он сложится из O(n) + O(log(n)) -> O(n) т.к. она растет быстрее чем логарифм.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Вопрос №1: Правильно ли я понимаю, что алгоритмическая сложность данного метода будет O(1)? Т.к. внутри используется HashMap со сложностью поиска и добавления O(1).

Да, с оговоркой про то, что вставка/поиск в хеше на неудачных данных может деградировать до *O(n)*,

Здесь стоит оговориться, что для хеша с адекватной хеш-функции, подходящем размере таблицы и при квазислучайных входных данных вероятность худшего случая пренебрежимо мала, но всегда существует такой набор данных, который этот случай даст. Зачастую его можно специально подобрать и даже [использовать](https://habr.com/post/178955/) для DOS-атаки.

Кроме того при обычной реализации динамически расширяемой хеш-таблицы `map.put` может потребовать перестроения индекса хеша, сложность которого также *O(n)*, но этого можно избежать заранее выделив под таблицу достаточный объём данных.

> Вопрос №2: Общая сложность системы будет равна O(n) ?

Да, с аналогичной оговоркой, в худшем случае время составит *O(n²)*.

В случае динамически расширяемой хеш таблицы в типовой реализации также необходимо увеличивать её размер и пересчитывать хеши порядка `log(N)` раз и время соответственно может ухудшиться до *O(N*log(N))* в среднем случае, но этот эффект будет проявляться только для относительно больших `N` и зачастую его так или иначе можно нивелировать (выделяя заведомо больше памяти).

---

> А теперь заменим HashMap на TreeMap:
>
> Вопрос №3: Сложность метода будет равна *O(log(n))* ?

Да

> Вопрос №4: Сложность всей системы будет равен O(n) ? Т.к. он сложится из O(n) + O(log(n)) -> O(n) т.к. она растет быстрее чем логарифм.

Нет, здесь не верно: нужно `N` раз сделать операцию сложностью *O(log(n))*, где `n` в среднем равно `N/2`. т.е. сложность будет *O(N*log(N))*.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но я не совсем понимаю: 1) В 99% процентах лит-ры сложность HashMap указывают O(1). О - это асимптотическая сложность  и тогда ее надо указывать для худшего случая т.е. она должна быть O(n) ? 2) Если сложность HashMap O(n), то в результате у нас будет сложность O(n^2) ? P.S. я знаю про ребалансировку HashMap, ее как-то учитывают в этой оценке или нет? Спасибо

Comment: 1) `O` указывается для среднего *или* худшего случая. Часто это пишут явно, но также часто авторы опускают это, подразумевая, что оно понятно из контекста; Дополнил ответ. 2) да; ЗЫ: *Ребалансируют* деревья, а хеш *перестраивают* (например, при увеличении размера таблицы), добавил комментарии по этому поводу в ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Да, все правильно. Перебор коллекции это всегда O(N), потому выполнение метода add и печать всех элементов это O(N). В первом случае сложность функции add - O(1) в среднем(а в худшем O(N), потому что в хеш-таблице могут быть коллизии), а во втором - O(log N) в худшем случае потому что TreeMap это сбалансированное бинарное дерево поиска.

**UPD** К сожалению слегка ошибся, забыл что во втором случае мы N раз добавляем за логарифм потому сложность O(N log N)

Answer (score 1):

*"Нужно написать алгоритм, который будет подсчитывать количество повторений* **цифр** *в этом файле."*

Скажите на милость, зачем вам вообще какие-то `HashMap`, если вас интересуют цифры? Массив из 10 целых, и вперед, чтение по одному символу, если цифра - увеличивать соответствующий элемент массива. Все. Чистое `O(размер файла)`.

Вы верно переписали задание? Просто в условии у вас одно задача, а решаете вы совсем другую.

Comment: Я ошибся в условии. Должно быть не цифр а чисел.