# Как посчитать сложность цикла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Скажите пожалуйста правильно ли я посчитал сложность алгоритма?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

a = [3, 2, 6, 34, 5]    # O(n)
for item in a:          # O(n)
    print(item)         # O(1)
```

Ход моих рассуждений выглядит так:

O(n) + O(n) = O(n + n) = O(2n) -> константу убираем -> **O(n)**

**O(n)** + O(1) = O(n + 1) -> константу убираем -> O(n)

Итоговая сложность всего алгоритма O(n)

Comment: Не дубликат, но связанный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/838194/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0#838203).

Comment: В первой строчке разве не О(1)? И вообще, учитывать надо только вторую строчку, т.к. только в ней есть алгоритм.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Итоговую сложность O(n) вы правильно определили.

Но сами вычисления ошибочны.

Во-первых, наивное сложение сложностей - это достаточно бессмысленная операция. Букву 'n' внутри О не следует рассматривать как какую-то алгебраическую величину. Нельзя взять одно O(n), сложить его с другим O(n) и получить O(2n).

'n' - это не какая-то конкретная величина, это условное обозначение линейной зависимости количества вычислительных итераций от количества входных данных. Наивные арифметические действия над 'n' в общем случае не отображают какую-то связь с какими бы то ни было величинами из реального мира.

Это как в анекдоте о прапорщике:

`- Допустим, число танков равно "М". Нет "М" мало, возьмем "N".`

Иными словами, анализ сложности - это скорее практическая инженерная дисциплина, нежели строгая математика. Хотя эта дисциплина и опирается на знания о поведении функций, взятые из матанализа.

Во-вторых, даже если для общих прикидок допустить использование арифметических операций над O, то для вложенных блоков кода выражения внутри O нужно перемножать, а не складывать.

То есть если внутри цикла сложностью O(n) выполняется операция сложностью O(1), то итоговую сложность следует оценивать вовсе не как O(n+1), а как O(n*1).

Для данного случая результат в итоге тот же получится, но вот если бы вы для вложенных циклов начали бы считать сложность, то сложение давало бы неправильный результат.